# Remove URL and Convert Special Characters in Text Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I've got a dataset. It's of scraped data and is pretty messy, it contains ASCII codes, HTML and URL's.

I'm trying to run 'langdetect' over it so that I split by language. However, it keeps throwing errors which I believe to be cause by the HTML and special characters etc. that are in the dataset.

As I'm carrying out NLP I need preserve/restore the punctuation of the text.

I have two problems which I'm struggling to solve:

1. How to convert the ASCII codes,in a pandas series, which have
   appeared during scraping into the associated char, given that I
   don't know the exact list of ASCII that will appear in the content
2. How do I remove URL's embedded in text in a pandas series?

The first question, I've research and haven't found a solution and genuinely don't know where to begin with it.

For the second question I've tried this solution but it doesn't seem to work

```
def removeurl(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('?P<url>https?://[^\s]+')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
    return removeurl
```

I've created a sample JSON file [here](https://files.fm/u/u6hu7wuv)

Comment: You might be able to get away with using [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to handle the encoded characters and isolate just text, eg: `your_column.apply(lambda L: bs4.BeautifulSoup(L, 'html.parser').get_text(' '))` and use that as a base to `.map(langdetect.detect)` - that seems to get you: `{'de': 3, 'en': 187, 'es': 1, 'fr': 2, 'id': 1, 'ja': 1, 'ko': 1, 'pl': 1, 'pt': 3}` for counts...

Comment: Visually it looks to have did it the trip but when I run it in `data.description.map(detect_langs)` I get the following error  `LangDetectException: No features in text.` which is the error I got previously.

Comment: Make a custom function to wrap the detection in a try/except and return None where it fails... Then filter those out and see what's going on?